# How to add the title to a Telerik report?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a report, which works fine. And now, I want to add a title to it. I would like the header to be the title of the report.
How shoud I proceed to get the above done?

Comment: You should clarify in which platform is the report.

Answer (score 0):

Set the name of the report like normal in the properties window. Then set the value of the Header's text element to:

`= ReportItem.ParentElement.ParentElement.ParentElement.Name`

Note that the number of ParentElements depends on how many nested elements the header textbox is in. For me, the correct number was three, as =ReportItem.Name returned something like "TextBox2", =ReportItem.ParentElement.Name, returned"Detail" and = ReportItem.ParentElement.ParentElement.Name returned nothing.

[Further reading](http://docs.telerik.com/reporting/allmembers-t-telerik-reporting-processing-reportitem#properties)